# Swift HTTP Json request returns Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Tags: json, swift

I have this request in my Swift code

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.website.com/Application/profile.php")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let postString = "get_comments=\(PostId)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("error=\(error!)")
        return
    }
    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
    }
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Any]
        print(jsonData)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

And in profile.php i have this code

```
if (isset($_POST['get_comments'])) {
    $PostId = $_POST['get_comments'];
    $response=["For errors",0,"Username"];
    echo json_decode($response);
}
```

But this code returns this following error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

And when i print `data` it prints "0 bytes".I tried doing what other answer suggested adding 
`request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`,but it didn't change anything

Comment: There are several bad practices in your Swift code, but the error itself seems to be in the backend. For the Swift part: don't use `.mutableContainers`, it has no effect in `Swift`. Also, casting the `JSON` to an array of `Any` is a bad idea usually.  Are you sure your `API` does not expect `JSON` data in the `POST` request's body? At the moment you are not sending `JSON`, but you are trying to decode the response as `JSON`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i mistook `json_decode` for `json_encode`,but even after changing it nothing changed.

Comment: What about the expected request body? Are you sure, it should be `.utf8` encoded data and not `JSON`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes i'm sending `get_comments=\(PostId)` which is not Json

Comment: Have you tried calling your API from another service, such as Postman? If you have a working request, after including it in the question, it will be easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i'll download it now

Comment: @DávidPásztor i tried it with Postman,but it also returned nothing.But maybe i'm doing something wrong in Postman

Comment: As suspected, you either have a backend issue or you are not configuring your request correctly.

Comment: @DávidPásztor In Postman i should add `get_comments="123"` to`raw` right?

Comment: I have no idea what format/encoding your backend is expecting, so I can't tell which format you should use. Try to understand your own backend and send the request data in the correct format.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i found my lame error.Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. My HTTP body is in String format and not JSON for eg. - "1234564".. I am appending data by encoding this string using .utf8.. but I get no response data..did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`PostId` was an optional value and i forgot to add `!`.The request looked like

`get_comments="Optional("12")"` which is wrong.